# Looking for an idiom opposite to "the more the merrier"

Tags: expressions, idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for an idiom or a phrase that expresses the opposite idea of ["the more the merrier"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+the+merrier).

Context:

> Five persons are taking a class in gymnastics with a private
>   coach. Only two show up for the training session. Person A: "Hey, [the
>   opposite of "the more the merrier"!"

The intended meaning is the two persons will receive more attention and useful advice from the coach, so the session stands a good chance of being more productive.

Ideally, the idiom should be usable in the example sentence above.

Note: I'm aware of ["less is more"](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Less+is+more), but I've heard it in the context of minimalism, and it doesn't sound like a good candidate here (correct me if I'm wrong.)

EDIT: "The more the merrier" is actually abbreviated. [Originally](https://books.google.com/books?id=9QuEiIMaBt0C&pg=PA298&lpg=PA298&dq=the%20fewer%20the%20better%20idiom&source=bl&ots=fHH-sHxO7g&sig=XZMANb2gfx_T5xE1AjQLRgVgRhs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEIQ6AEwB2oVChMIzr6DtMqZyQIVaL1yCh0k5Q8A#v=onepage&q&f=false) it was **"the more the merrier; the fewer, the better fare"**, where "fare" means food. One could of course simply say "the fewer the better", but I'd like something more colorful, if possible. And "the fewer, the better fare" sounds a bit opaque (again, correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: The fewer the better fare https://books.google.fr/books?id=7PMZJqSR4sAC&pg=PA395&dq=%22the+fewer+the+better%22&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBTgKahUKEwiGxM-EyZnJAhXJwBQKHaarDYI#v=onepage&q=%22the%20fewer%20the%20better%22&f=false

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that, but I was hoping for something more colorful than "the fewer the better", and something less opaque than "the fewer the better fare"

Comment: "fare" can actually be used by extension...

Comment: fare: something offered to the public, as for entertainment: literary fare; Archaic. the state of things.

Comment: I suggest you create your own idiom, specific to the scene in the gym. Use words like jump, sprint/ bump, splint (fewer jumping, less bumping). Play with it.

Comment: @Elian Would you consider posting "the fewer the better fare" as an answer? Your initial comment ("the fewer the better") reminded me of the original full version of "the more the merrier", and so was helpful. I ended up deciding that "the fewer the better fare" is the way to go, wish the expression was a bit clearer, but oh well... it still fits my context best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment above, consider ***the fewer, the better fare***.

> The More The Merrier The larger the number involved, the better the
>   occasion. For example, John's invited all his family to come along,
>   and why not? The more the merrier. This expression was first recorded
>   in 1530, when it was put as “**The more the merrier; the fewer, the
>   better fare” (meaning “with fewer there would be more to eat**”), an
>   observation that made its way into numerous proverb collections.

[The American Heritage® Idioms Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/more-the-merrier--the)

Answer (score 2):

***[Two is a company three is a crowd](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/two-s-company-three-s-a-crowd)***  may suggest the idea:

> - said when two ​people are ​relaxed and ​enjoying each other's ​company but another ​person would make them ​feel less ​comfortable

you could use also the following, making it sound less serious:

***[better be alone than in bad company](http://www.english-for-students.com/better-be-alone-than-in-bad-company.html):***

> - It is better to be called a loner than to be labeled as a bad person. It is better off to be without any friends than to have friends with a bad character. You are known by the company you keep. So we must be careful while choosing our friends.

There is an interesting Italian proverb that says :

***"the best wine is always in the small barrel"*** that suggests that the best things are found or done in small entities or but few people.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't considered "crowd" and related words or expressions. That said, isn't "three is a crowd" synonymous with "fifth wheel"?

Comment: @A.P. -        Yes, but the saying is also used when you want to suggest that there are too many, more than necessary, people in a given context, not only in a romantic one.

Comment: There seems to be not many expressions for the question. I think your answer is good.

Answer (score 1):

**Too many cooks spoil the broth**

> Too many persons involved in managing an activity can ruin it

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/too+many+cooks+spoil+the+broth

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I think this would work if, instead of one, three *coaches* showed up :) This proverb is about *managing*, not participation, no?

Comment: Ah if 3 coaches showed up I think that would be "too many chiefs, not enough Indians"