# Is there a word for using half an idiom or saying?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Sometimes, when engaged in conversation, English-speakers will say the first half of a well-known saying or idiom, trailing off at the end or punctuating it with a shrug.  For instance, they might say "Birds of a feather..." or "When in Rome..." and leaving the "flock together" and "do as the Romans do" completely unsaid, when arguably that unspoken portion was the whole point of their statement in the first place.

Is there a name for such abbreviated usage?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The technical term,  *anapodoton* is an appropriate, and perhaps more accurate alternative to *ellipsis*

> An **[anapodoton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anapodoton)** (from the Greek *anapodosis*: "without a main clause") is a rhetorical device related to the *anacoluthon*. **It is a figure of speech or discourse that is an incomplete sentence**, consisting of a subject or complement without the requisite object. The stand-alone subordinate clause suggests or implies a subject (a main clause), but this is not actually provided.
>
> As an intentional rhetorical device, it is generally used for set phrases, where the full form is understood, and would thus be tedious to spell out, as in “When in Rome [do as the Romans].” or “If the mountain won't come to Muhammad [Muhammed will go to the mountain].”

You might also call them *clipped*,  or simply, *shortened idioms*. Here is a list  of *shortened idioms* that I found scouring the ELU archives.

- **great minds**
  derived from *[Good wits doe jumpe](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/295446/44619)*, which transformed into
  *Great minds think alike*
- **Pot, kettle, black**
  Derived from *The pot calls the pan burnt-arse*, which later became
  *[The pot calling the kettle black](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/164004)*
- **devil-may-care**
  Originally: *[The devil may care, but I do not](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/324782/etymology-of-devil-may-care)*
- **second nature**
  derived from an ancient proverb: *[Custom (or usage) is a second nature](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320378/having-done-something-so-often-that-its-all-routine/320399#320399)*
- **speak of the devil**
  derived from *[Speak of the devil and he doth appear](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/162103/44619)*
- **the last/final straw**
  originally:  *[The straw that broke the camel's back](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/360959)*
- **the more the merrier**
  derived from: *[The more the merrier; the fewer, the better fare](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/287931/looking-for-an-idiom-opposite-to-the-more-the-merrier)*
- **when in Rome**
  Originally: *[When in Rome, do as the Romans do](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/285112/english-idiom-or-proverb-equivalent-for-if-everybody-is-doing-it-i-will-also-d/285167#285167)*
- **every man for himself**
  Originally: *[Every man for himself, and the Devil take the hindmost](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/every+man+for+himself)*

Comment: Stunning answer! +1. I too think that ellipsis isn't specific enough.

Comment: Awesome!  Certainly didn't expect an answer after six months, nor one that actually solved the question.  Thanks!

Comment: Great answer. I'm not so sure on a couple of your examples though: both "the more the merrier" and "every man for himself" stand on their own, without needing the rest of the original idiom. Hence although they are "shortened idioms" I don't believe they are anapodotons.

Answer (score 9):

I found a noble page with many rhetorical devices described. Included is the paradoxical [Inclusion by Omission](http://wordsinaction.info/ecw/evtp/rhetoric.html#inclusion_by_omission):

There are two words that may apply.

> **aposiopesis**
>
> An unfinished thought or broken sentence.
>   "If you don't eat up that spinach, I'll..."
>
> **ellipsis**
>
> Omission of one or more words.
>   "If only pigs could fly!"

Please also see this Wikipedia page on [Ellipsis (linguistic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)).

> In linguistics, ellipsis (from the Greek: ἔλλειψις, élleipsis, "omission") or elliptical construction refers to the omission from a clause of one or more words that are nevertheless understood in the context of the remaining elements.